# Go+Echoのバリデーションチェックで型エラーでもエラーメッセージを出したい

Tags: go, バリデーション, go-echo

Go + Echo + play-glound/validatorを利用して下記のような処理を入れています。

```golang
if err := c.Bind(&user); err != nil {
    return err
}

err := c.Validate(user)

if err != nil {
    return c.Render(http.StatusOK, "user_form.html", err)
}
```

型エラーがある場合、c.Bindでエラーとなってしまい、c.Validateまで行きません。
またc.Bindでエラーとなると、エラーとなったフィールドの特定もできません。

c.Bindでの型エラーとc.Validateでの必須チェックなどを同列に画面表示させたいのですが、良い書き方はあるでしょうか？

※なお、この質問はteratailにも併せて投稿しております。
https://teratail.com/questions/fjhdbys3wa7qq1

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/fjhdbys3wa7qq1) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Answer (score 2):

（echo v4.11.4 を前提とします）

#### 標準のBindとValidateのエラーを同時に読むことに意味は無いです

> c.Bindでの型エラーとc.Validateでの必須チェックなどを同列に画面表示させたい

これは意味が無いと思います。

##### Bindに失敗すると結果（渡した構造体）は無意味なデータとなる

[Bind](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/labstack/echo/v4@v4.11.4#DefaultBinder.Bind) がリクエストデータの解析に失敗して error を返した際、対象の構造体がどういった状態になっているかは、何も説明されていません。途中まで解析に成功していたフィールドの値はセットされているかも知れませんし、何も触られていないかも知れません。用心深く考えるならば、適当な一時的な値になっているかも知れません。

現在の実装に何かしらの法則が有ったとしても、それに依存するべきではありません（これを予測可能で意味の有る値にするように[自作した](https://echo.labstack.com/docs/binding#custom-binding)場合は、もちろん別の話ですが）。

##### 無意味なデータをValidateした結果は無意味

解析に失敗した結果、何が入っているか不明なデータをValidateで検証しても無意味です。おそらく検証エラーになるでしょうが、それを読んで何かを判断するべきではありません。